# How to detect a malware which is fragmented across multiple packets

Tags: malware

How can we detect a malware which is fragmented across many packets , do we have to do some prefix /suffix matching kind of approach?
Does tools like snort,Suricata support this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some information (like malware) is spread across multiple packets then the obvious way to detect this would be to reassemble the traffic like the endpoint of the connection would do.

Modern IDS like snort or Suricata support such reassembling. Of course this comes with a cost in memory and loss of performance since more information need to be stored and processed. And it is also possible to trick a passive IDS which just watches the packets into reassembling packets differently than the endpoint system would do, like with overlapping segments, packets with different TTL or similar. This way the IDS will see different traffic than the endpoint, which allows bypassing analysis.

For a more reliable analysis one can use application layer gateways (also called application proxies), which fully terminate the TCP connections from one peer and create new ones to the other peer. This implicitly normalizes the traffic at the transport layer which makes packet level tricks impossible.  It also makes sanitizing the traffic at the application layer possible. Unfortunately it also comes with even more costs and less performance than packet reassembly in IDS.